# How to get a list of all Jenkins nodes assigned with label including master node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm creating a Jenkins pipeline job and I need to run a job on all nodes labelled with a certain label.

Therefore I'm trying to get a list of node names assigned with a certain label. (With a node I can get the labels with `getAssignedLabels()`)

The `nodes`-list in `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes` seems not contain the master-node which I need to include in my search.

My current solution is to iterate over the `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers` and use the `getNode()`-method to get the node. This works, but in the javadoc of Jenkins I'm reading the this list might not be up-to-date.

In the long-run I will add (dynamically) cloud-nodes and I'm afraid that I won't be able to use `computers` then.

What is the right way to get the list of all current nodes?

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
@NonCPS
def nodeNames(label) {
    def nodes = []
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
        if (c.node.labelString.contains(label)) {
            nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
        }
    }   
    return nodes
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the way I'm doing it right now. I haven't found anything else:

```
@NonCPS
def hostNames(label) {
  def nodes = []
  jenkins.model.Jenkins.get().computers.each { c ->
    if (c.node.labelString.contains(label)) {
      nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
    }
  }
  return nodes
}
```

`jenkins.model.Jenkins.get.computers` contains the master-node and all the slaves.

Comment: @Oliver changed the code from `Jenkins.instance.computers` to `Jenkins.get.computers` - how he known what he's doing.

Comment: Luke, read the source! https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/Jenkins.java#L818

Comment: Your code results in `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: get for class: jenkins.model.Jenkins`. Please change `jenkins.model.Jenkins.get` to `jenkins.model.Jenkins.get()`

Answer (score 19):

Updated answer: in a pipeline use [`nodesByLabel`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#nodesbylabel-list-of-nodes-by-label-by-default-excludes-offline-nodes) to get all nodes assigned to a label.

Comment: This is the more modern answer. You can even do something like this:

`nodeList = nodesByLabel label: 'LABEL1||LABEL2&&!ANOTHER', offline: true`

Comment: To use it, you need to install `Pipeline Utility Steps`. See https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/

Answer (score 9):

Here is a functional solution which is more readable and concise:

```
def nodes = jenkins.model.Jenkins.get().computers
  .findAll{ it.node.labelString.contains(label) }
  .collect{ it.node.selfLabel.name }
```

You can verify it in the Jenkins [Script Console](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/).

Answer (score 8):

Update to @patrick-b answer : contains can be buggy if you have labels containing same string, I've added a split step do check every label separated with spaces.

```
@NonCPS
def hostNames(label) {
    def nodes = []
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.get.computers.each { c ->
        c.node.labelString.split(/\s+/).each { l ->
            if (l != null && l.equals(label)) {
                nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
             }
        }
    }

    return nodes
}
```

Comment: The code above always returned an empty list for me. The `l.equals(label)` actually needed to be `(l == label)'.

I also added an 'if ( c.isOnline() )` check to ensure only online slaves were returned.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do this with:

```
def nodes = Jenkins.get.getLabel('my-label').getNodes()
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
    node(nodes[i].getNodeName()) {
        // on node
    }
}
```

I don't know for sure whether this works with cloud nodes.

Comment: Yes. It does work with cloud nodes. We use something like this:
`nodes = Jenkins.instance.getLabel('GO_BUILDER||BASIC_SLAVE').getNodes().collect{it.getNodeName()}`

BASIC_SLAVEs are Cloud nodes in our case.  You can even include a label on your Master, but beware, master node returns as an empty string!

Comment: Upvoted because this method allows label expressions to be used (e.g. 'my-label&&my-other-label') which none of the other non-pipeline answers do.

Answer (score 2):

using `nodesByLabel` as pointed out by @towel is probably the solution in most cases. One limitation I found with `nodesByLabel`  is that there is no way to indiscriminately select *all* nodes. I can't use any of the other solutions either because of script security, some of these can be pretty dangerous, so I preferred not to approve them for usage.

As an alternatively, you can add a function as a pipeline library, which will allow usage of these functions. Since pipeline libraries can be set up so they are fully under the administrator's control, it's safer to go with this route. To do so, set up a pipeline library (I don't think it matters if it's global or not, but for me it is). Then add the following contents to the file `vars/parallelRunOnNodes.groovy`:

```
def call(Closure callback) {
    parallel jenkins.model.Jenkins.get().computers.collectEntries { agent ->
        def nodeLabel = agent.node.selfLabel.name
        ["${nodeLabel}": {
            node("${nodeLabel}") {
                stage("${nodeLabel}") {
                    callback(nodeLabel)
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Parallel on all nodes') {
            steps {
                parallelRunOnNodes { nodeLabel ->
                    println(nodeLabel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously adjust as you see fit, e.g. you can add additional parameters to filter, maybe you don't care about parallel etc.

Comment: Great solution! I was trying to edit it so it can only create stages for nodes with labels containing a specific word. Can you help please? I tried adding `agent.node.labelString.contains("label-")` but it fails with `No such property: Entry for class: java.util.Map` I think because *contains* returns boolean not Map.

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan you want to filter the nodes first prior to the `collectEntries` call. Something like `jenkins.model.Jenkins.get().computers.findAll { it.node.selfLabel.name.contains("label-) }.collectEntries ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try using
`for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {}` and `aSlave.getLabelString());` to get all the labels for all of your nodes. You can construct a list of nodes per label this way.

Comment: `slaves` is depcecated (you should use `nodes`) and `nodes` does not contain the master-node.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
String labelIWantServersOf = "XXXX"; // This is the label assosiated with nodes for which i want the server names of
List serverList = [];

for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {          
  if (aSlave.getLabelString().indexOf(labelIWantServersOf ) > -1) {
     if(!aSlave.getComputer().isOffline() ){
          serverList.add(aSlave.name);        
     }
  }    
}

return serverList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another wat to get `Labels` and `Display Name` of nodes

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
def computers = jenkins.computers
computers.each {
   println "${it.displayName} ${it.hostName}"
}

def labels = jenkins.getLabels()
labels.each {
   println "${it.displayName}"
}
```

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers –

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answers from the original question and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54145233/1817610 and saved it as a shared library method

### vars/nodeNames.groovy

```
def call(String label) {
    def nodes = []
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
        c.node.labelString.split(/\s+/).each { l ->
            if (l != null && l.equals(label)) {
                nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
             }
        }
    }
    return nodes
}
```

Once the shared library is configured, see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/, this can be used as

```
@Library("my-jenkins-shared-lib") _

print ("linux pipeline can run on" + nodeNames("linux"))
```

Answer (score -2):

This is one of the top Google hits for how to list nodes on a Jenkins server. If you're just looking for the list of nodes, it can be viewed at the following server URL:

```
http://JENKINS_HOSTNAME:JENKINS_PORT/computer/
```

The result is a table displaying the name, OS, JVM version, clock sync status, remoting version and response time of known nodes. It also displays whether the node image (well, JAR) is significantly outdated or subject to error/security alerts.

If there is no access available to API calls, the URL can always be scraped and parsed to get the list of nodes and any of the other data included in the table.