# How to trigger a Jenkins Job on multiple nodes from a Pipeline (only one job executing)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Job, configured as a **Scripted Jenkins Pipeline**, which:

1. Checks out the code from GitHub
2. merges in developer changes
3. builds a debug image

it is then supposed to split into 3 separate parallel processes - one of which builds the release version of the code and unit tests it.
The other 2 processes are supposed to be identical, with the debug image being flashed onto a target and various tests running.

The targets are identified in Jenkins as ***slave_1*** and ***slave_2*** and are both allocated the label ***131_ci_targets***

I am using 'parallel' to trigger the release build, and the multiple instances of the test job. I will post a (slightly redacted) copy of my Scripted pipeline below for full reference, but for the question I have tried all 3 of the following options.

1. Using a single `build` call with `LabelParamaterValue` and `allNodesMatchingLabel` set to `true`. In this the TEST_TARGETS is the label *131_ci_targets*

```
parallel_steps = [:]
parallel_steps["release"] = { // Release build and test steps
}

parallel_steps["${TEST_TARGETS}"] = {
    stage("${TEST_TARGETS}") {
        build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
              parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"),
                           string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: "${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}"),
                           [$class: 'LabelParameterValue',
                            name: 'RUN_NODE', label: "${TEST_TARGETS}",
                            allNodesMatchingLabel: true,
                            nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
    }
} // ${TEST_TARGETS}

stage('Parallel'){
    parallel parallel_steps
} // Parallel
```

2. Using a single `build` call with `NodeParamaterValue` and a list of all nodes. In this TEST_TARGETS is again the label, while test_nodes is a list of 2 strings: `[slave_1, slave_2]`

```
parallel_steps = [:]
parallel_steps["release"] = { // Release build and test steps
}

test_nodes = hostNames("${TEST_TARGETS}")

parallel_steps["${TEST_TARGETS}"] = {
    stage("${TEST_TARGETS}") {
        echo "test_nodes: ${test_nodes}"
        build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
              parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"),
                           string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: "${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}"),
                           [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',
                            name: 'RUN_NODE', labels: test_nodes,
                            nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
    }
} // ${TEST_TARGETS}

stage('Parallel'){
    parallel parallel_steps
} // Parallel
```

3: Using multiple stages, each with a single `build` call with `NodeParamaterValue` and a list containing only 1 slave id.
test_nodes is the list of strings : `[slave_1, slave_2]`, while the first call passes `slave_1` and the second `slave_2`.

```
        for ( tn in test_nodes ) {
            parallel_steps["${tn}"] = {
                stage("${tn}") {
                    echo "test_nodes: ${test_nodes}"
                    build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
                          parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"),
                                       string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: "${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}"),
                                       [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',
                                        name: 'RUN_NODE', labels: [tn],
                                        nodeEligibility: [$class: 'IgnoreOfflineNodeEligibility']]],
                          wait: false
                }
            } // ${tn}
        }
```

All of the above will trigger only a single run of the 'Trial_Test_Pipe' on `slave_2` assuming that both `slave_1` and `slave_2` are defined, online and have available executors.

The Trial_Test_Pipe job is another Jenkins Pipeline job, and has the checkbox "Do not allow concurrent builds" unchecked.

Any thoughts on:

- Why the job will only trigger one of the runs, not both?
- What the correct solution may be?

For reference now: here is my full(ish) scripted Jenkins job:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import java.net.URL

def BUILD_SLAVE=""

// clean the workspace before starting the build process
def clean_before_build() {
    bat label:'',
        script: '''cd %GITHUB_REPO_PATH%
                   git status
                   git clean -x -d -f
                   '''
}

// Routine to build the firmware
// Can build Debug or Release depending on the environment variables
def build_the_firmware() {
    return
    def batch_script = """
        REM *** Build script here
        echo "... Build script here ..."
        """

    bat label:'',
        script: batch_script
}

// Copy the hex files out of the Build folder and into the Jenkins workspace
def copy_hex_files_to_workspace() {
    return
    def batch_script = """
        REM *** Copy HEX file to workspace:
        echo "... Copy HEX file to workspace ..."
        """

    bat label:'',
        script: batch_script
}

// Updated from stackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54145233/1589770
@NonCPS
def hostNames(label) {
    nodes = []
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
        if ( c.isOnline() ){
            labels = c.node.labelString
            labels.split(' ').each { l ->
                if (l == label) {
                    nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nodes
}

try {
    node('Build_Slave') {
        BUILD_SLAVE = "${env.NODE_NAME}"
        echo "build_slave=${BUILD_SLAVE}"

        stage('Checkout Repo') {
            // Set a desription on the build history to make for easy identification
            currentBuild.setDescription("Pull Request: ${PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER} \n${TARGET_BRANCH}")

            echo "... checking out dev code from our repo ..."
        } // Checkout Repo

        stage ('Merge PR') {
            // Merge the base branch into the target for test
            echo "... Merge the base branch into the target for test ..."
        } // Merge PR

        stage('Build Debug') {
            withEnv(['LIB_MODE=Debug', 'IMG_MODE=Debug', 'OUT_FOLDER=Debug']){
                clean_before_build()
                build_the_firmware()
                copy_hex_files_to_workspace()

                archiveArtifacts "${LIB_MODE}\\*.hex, ${LIB_MODE}\\*.map"
            }
        } // Build Debug

        stage('Post Build') {
            if (currentBuild.resultIsWorseOrEqualTo("UNSTABLE")) {
                echo "... Send a mail to the Admins and the Devs ..."
            }
        } // Post Merge

    } // node

    parallel_steps = [:]
    parallel_steps["release"] = {
        node("${BUILD_SLAVE}") {
            stage('Build Release') {
                withEnv(['LIB_MODE=Release', 'IMG_MODE=Release', 'OUT_FOLDER=build\\Release']){
                    clean_before_build()
                    build_the_firmware()
                    copy_hex_files_to_workspace()

                    archiveArtifacts "${LIB_MODE}\\*.hex, ${LIB_MODE}\\*.map"
                }
            } // Build Release
            stage('Unit Tests') {
                echo "... do Unit Tests here ..."
            }
        }
    } // release

    test_nodes = hostNames("${TEST_TARGETS}")

    if (true) {
        parallel_steps["${TEST_TARGETS}"] = {
            stage("${TEST_TARGETS}") {
                echo "test_nodes: ${test_nodes}"
                build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
                      parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"),
                                   string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: "${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}"),
                                   [$class: 'LabelParameterValue',
                                    name: 'RUN_NODE', label: "${TEST_TARGETS}",
                                    allNodesMatchingLabel: true,
                                    nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
            }
        } // ${TEST_TARGETS}
    } else if ( false ) {
        parallel_steps["${TEST_TARGETS}"] = {
            stage("${TEST_TARGETS}") {
                echo "test_nodes: ${test_nodes}"
                build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
                      parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"),
                                   string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: "${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}"),
                                   [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',
                                    name: 'RUN_NODE', labels: test_nodes,
                                    nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
            }
        } // ${TEST_TARGETS}
    } else {
        for ( tn in test_nodes ) {
            parallel_steps["${tn}"] = {
                stage("${tn}") {
                    echo "test_nodes: ${test_nodes}"
                    build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
                          parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: "${TARGET_BRANCH}"),
                                       string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: "${FRAMEWORK_VERSION}"),
                                       [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',
                                        name: 'RUN_NODE', labels: [tn],
                                        nodeEligibility: [$class: 'IgnoreOfflineNodeEligibility']]],
                          wait: false
                }
            } // ${tn}
        }
    }

    stage('Parallel'){
        parallel parallel_steps
    } // Parallel
} // try
catch (Exception ex) {
    if ( manager.logContains(".*Merge conflict in .*") ) {
        manager.addWarningBadge("Pull Request ${PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER} Experienced Git Merge Conflicts.")
        manager.createSummary("warning.gif").appendText("<h2>Experienced Git Merge Conflicts!</h2>", false, false, false, "red")
    }

    echo "... Send a mail to the Admins and the Devs ..."

    throw ex
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... I have a solution for this ... as in, I understand what to do, and why one of the above solutions wasn't working.

The winner is ***Option 3*** ... the reason it wasn't working is that the code inside the enclosure (the `stage` part) isn't evaluated until the stage is actually being run. As a result the strings aren't expanded until then and, since `tn` is fixed at `slave_2` by that point, that's the value used on both parallel streams.

In the Jenkins examples here ... [https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-grep] ... the enclosures are returned from a function `transformIntoStep` and by doing this I was able to force early evaluation of the strings and so get parallel steps running on both slaves.

If you're here looking for answers, I hope this helps. If you are, and it has, please feel free to give me an uptick. Cheers :)

My final scripted jenkinsfile looks something like this:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import java.net.URL

BUILD_SLAVE=""
parallel_steps = [:]

// clean the workspace before starting the build process
def clean_before_build() {
    bat label:'',
        script: '''cd %GITHUB_REPO_PATH%
                   git status
                   git clean -x -d -f
                   '''
}

// Routine to build the firmware
// Can build Debug or Release depending on the environment variables
def build_the_firmware() {
    def batch_script = """
        REM *** Build script here
        echo "... Build script here ..."
        """

    bat label:'',
        script: batch_script
}

// Copy the hex files out of the Build folder and into the Jenkins workspace
def copy_hex_files_to_workspace() {
    def batch_script = """
        REM *** Copy HEX file to workspace:
        echo "... Copy HEX file to workspace ..."
        """

    bat label:'',
        script: batch_script
}

// Updated from stackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54145233/1589770
@NonCPS
def hostNames(label) {
    nodes = []
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
        if ( c.isOnline() ){
            labels = c.node.labelString
            labels.split(' ').each { l ->
                if (l == label) {
                    nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nodes
}

def transformTestStep(nodeId) {
    return {
        stage(nodeId) {
            build job: 'Trial_Test_Pipe',
                  parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_BRANCH', value: TARGET_BRANCH),
                               string(name: 'FRAMEWORK_VERSION', value: FRAMEWORK_VERSION),
                               [$class: 'NodeParameterValue',
                                name: 'RUN_NODE', labels: [nodeId],
                                nodeEligibility: [$class: 'IgnoreOfflineNodeEligibility']]],
                  wait: false
        }
    }
}

def transformReleaseStep(build_slave) {
    return {
        node(build_slave) {
            stage('Build Release') {
                withEnv(['LIB_MODE=Release', 'IMG_MODE=Release', 'OUT_FOLDER=build\\Release']){
                    clean_before_build()
                    build_the_firmware()
                    copy_hex_files_to_workspace()

                    archiveArtifacts "${LIB_MODE}\\*.hex, ${LIB_MODE}\\*.map"
                }
            } // Build Release
            stage('Unit Tests') {
                echo "... do Unit Tests here ..."
            }
        }
    }
}


try {
    node('Build_Slave') {
        BUILD_SLAVE = "${env.NODE_NAME}"
        echo "build_slave=${BUILD_SLAVE}"

        parallel_steps["release"] = transformReleaseStep(BUILD_SLAVE)

        test_nodes = hostNames("${TEST_TARGETS}")
        for ( tn in test_nodes ) {
            parallel_steps[tn] = transformTestStep(tn)
        }

        stage('Checkout Repo') {
            // Set a desription on the build history to make for easy identification
            currentBuild.setDescription("Pull Request: ${PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER} \n${TARGET_BRANCH}")

            echo "... checking out dev code from our repo ..."
        } // Checkout Repo

        stage ('Merge PR') {
            // Merge the base branch into the target for test
            echo "... Merge the base branch into the target for test ..."
        } // Merge PR

        stage('Build Debug') {
            withEnv(['LIB_MODE=Debug', 'IMG_MODE=Debug', 'OUT_FOLDER=Debug']){
                clean_before_build()
                build_the_firmware()
                copy_hex_files_to_workspace()

                archiveArtifacts "${LIB_MODE}\\*.hex, ${LIB_MODE}\\*.map"
            }
        } // Build Debug

        stage('Post Build') {
            if (currentBuild.resultIsWorseOrEqualTo("UNSTABLE")) {
                echo "... Send a mail to the Admins and the Devs ..."
            }
        } // Post Merge

    } // node

    stage('Parallel'){
        parallel parallel_steps
    } // Parallel

} // try
catch (Exception ex) {
    if ( manager.logContains(".*Merge conflict in .*") ) {
        manager.addWarningBadge("Pull Request ${PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER} Experienced Git Merge Conflicts.")
        manager.createSummary("warning.gif").appendText("<h2>Experienced Git Merge Conflicts!</h2>", false, false, false, "red")
    }

    echo "... Send a mail to the Admins and the Devs ..."

    throw ex
}
```